# How to Optimise View?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle11g, sql-view

The following View returns result after very long time. How to optmise it for quick result ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_e_soa
  AS
    SELECT substr(account_id,1,16) account_id,
           stmt_on_email,
           MIN(curr_no) curr_no,
           co_code,
           ( SELECT convert_to_date(MIN(date_time) )
             FROM ext_account_his_31122017 y
             WHERE y.stmt_on_email = x.stmt_on_email
                   AND   substr(y.account_id,1,16) = substr(x.account_id,1,16)
           ) date_time
    FROM ext_account_his_31122017 x
    WHERE stmt_on_email = 'YES'
    GROUP BY substr(account_id,1,16),
             stmt_on_email,
             co_code;
```

Comment: depends on the execution plan of the select statement.

Comment: First, remove the substr part. Implement this part before inserting data, by creating a separate column, if its possible.

Comment: What's the datatype of column `date_time`, and what does the function `convert_ to_date` do?

Comment: @wolφi date_time  has date and time in 201806200119 formate. convert_t_date convert it to date like 20-jun-2018 01:19 etc

Comment: OK, thanks. Calling a function very often can be quite expensive. I'd try the built in TO_DATE(), and see if it is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing your table structure and minimal example data (please edit your post and show us!), I'd try to attact the following point:

1. look into substr(account_id), what's the reason for chopping of digits after position 16. Is account_id a VARCHAR2 or a NUMBER?
2. You filter on stmt_on_email = 'YES'. This could possibly be done at an earlier stage (for instance with a `WITH` clause). There is no reason to have it in the GROUP BY clause.
3. The biggest gain is probaby in the SEELCT convert_to_date clause. It requires a self join of the table, and calls a function for each row. Both is probably not necessary.

I would try something along the lines of:

```
WITH 
filtered_stmt_yes AS (
  SELECT substr(account_id,1,16) account_id,
         stmt_on_email,
         curr_no,
         co_code,
         to_date(date_time,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') as date_time
    FROM ext_account_his_31122017 x
   WHERE stmt_on_email = 'YES'
   ORDER BY account_id),
ranked AS (
  SELECT account_id, stmt_on_email, curr_no, co_code, date_time,
         min(curr_no) over (partition by account_id, co_code) as min_curr_no,
         min(date_time) over (partition by account_id) as min_date_time,
         row_number() over (partition by account_id order by rowid) as r
    FROM filtered_stmt_yes)
SELECT account_id, 
       stmt_on_email, 
       min_curr_no as cur_no, 
       co_code, 
       min_date_time as date_time
  FROM ranked
 WHERE r=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the minimum date over per account you can switch to a Group Min instead of a Scalar Correlated Subquery:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_e_soa
  AS
    SELECT substr(account_id,1,16) account_id,
           stmt_on_email,
           MIN(curr_no) curr_no,
           co_code,
           convert_to_date(MIN(MIN(date_time)) -- aggregate Min nested in OLAP Min
                           OVER (PARTITION BY substr(account_id,1,16)) date_time
    FROM ext_account_his_31122017 x
    WHERE stmt_on_email = 'YES'
    GROUP BY substr(account_id,1,16),
             stmt_on_email,
             co_code;
```